# Which method is called the first one if we have overriden methods in Java?

Tags: java

As I know, if we have overridden methods in Java the first one which is called is overridden one. In this case I have initialized `Dog` object and I call method `f` which has one String inside. Class `Tomato` extends class `Food`. But why in this case I get as an answer `null` when it cleary should be *tomato* name and *blee* at the end?

```
public class Animal {
    String name;

    public void f(Food t) {
        System.out.println(t.name);
    }
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
    String name;

    public void f(Tomato t) {
        System.out.println(t.name + "blee");
    }
}
```

and this is call:

tomato is subclass of food!

```
Tomato t = new Tomato();
    t.name = "jdfjkgdlkg";


    Animal amor = new Dog();

    amor.f(t);
```

Comment: You have not overridden `f` in `Dog`; the parameter types in the method must be the same.

Comment: We haven't seen how the call to `f` was written, and it matters here.

Comment: You also are shadowing `Animal.name` in `Dog`, which is why you're getting `null`.

Comment: i have added additional code.. i really dont get it, if i call function f on dog object and as argument i pass tomato how is it possible that animal object is called and not dog?

Answer (score 2):

overriden method has equals signature

This

```
public void f(Food t)
```

and this

```
public void f(Tomato t)
```

are different methods

If you want to override method you should write this in Dog class

```
public void f(Food t) {

    System.out.println(t.name + "blee");
}
```

Comment: (you don't/shouldn't put javascript snippet tags around java code, they dont' work and just clutter your answer)

Comment: I should paste java code into "Code Sample"? @SnakeDoc

Comment: no, just use the back-tick ` or 4 spaces in front of your sample. Raw Java code can't run in the browser, so the code snippet tags don't do any good.

Comment: I had read that you can use subclass arguments and it is still overriden method